# How do I assign value of button.setAttribute('name', 'value') a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

First, here is the javascript code.

```
    const nameId = calledVariable.value // This variable is an input from a form

    // Create the button
    var payButton = document.createElement('input');
    payButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    payButton.setAttribute('value', 'UNPAID');
    payButton.setAttribute('class', 'unpaidButton');
    payButton.setAttribute('id', nameId); // This needs to be text of input
    payButton.setAttribute('onClick', 'updateButton(this.id)');
```

and this is the HTML result

```
<input type="button" value="UNPAID" class="unpaidButton" id="" onclick="updateButton(this.id)">
```

How do I get the HTML/javascript to recognize `nameId` as it's value?

Comment: Just to be clear, I needed the `input` `id` to equal `nameId` in the HTML, this was solved by changing one thing in the following line:  `payButton.setAttribute('id', nameId);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I solved my own question... use the following in the code...

```
payButton.setAttribute('id', `${nameId}`);
```

This is a Facepalm moment...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ${...} to pass the var value to the setAttribute function. Use only the variable name. Like that:

```js
const nameId = 123;
const payButton = document.querySelector('button');
console.log('before', payButton)
payButton.setAttribute('id', nameId);

const check = document.querySelector('button');
console.log('after',check)
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: That didn't set an id attribute to the button, the solutions should have provided this...
`<button id="123">button</button>`